# Valve reassembly

Tags: valve

After cleaning my valves and the ports, I am about ready to put them back in together.  I have two simple questions:

1. Should I clean the inside of valve guides with a pipe cleaner, that looks like a mini chimney brush?  I already cleaned it really well with an air pistol.

[image: pipe cleaner]

2. Should I first install the valve stem seals and then set the valves back in for lapping or should I lap first and put the stem seal after lapping and right before the rest of assembly (loading the spring)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. Should I clean the inside of valve guides with a pipe cleaner, that looks like a mini chimney brush? I already cleaned it really well with an air pistol.

Spray some solvent (like carb cleaner) down the valve guides followed by the air pistol. While I don't think you'd have any issues using the pipe cleaner, I don't really think it would do much for you either.

> 2. Should I first install the valve stem seals and then set the valves back in for lapping or should I lap first and put the stem seal after lapping and right before the rest of assembly (loading the spring)?

Wait until you have all the valves lapped, everything is cleaned, and are ready for final assembly. The valves will go in first, then the seals on top of the valves, then spring seats, springs, retainers, and keys. Make sure the valve stem is lubed well with oil and be careful with the seals. The tips of the valve stems can be sharp and cause damage to the new seals.

Comment: thanks.  one more sub questions:  how do I know the seal has sealed properly when I set it?

Comment: @amphibient - The bottom of the seal should be flush against the head. If you happen to damage one, buy another set and replace it. If you don't, it will pump oil down into that cylinder. *Very important*.